# What to do with wet socks?

Tags: clothing, comfort, weather

During the rainy season I often step in a puddle and get wet socks. I normally just change them when I get home but this seems like a waste and causes me to do laundry more frequently. Is there a way I can quickly dry them? I've tried using a fan electric heater but it doesn't work well and also seems wasteful if you have it on just for a pair of socks.

Comment: Related: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/228/how-to-quickly-dry-wet-sneakers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bring a couple pairs to change. After you get home, instead of throw it into laundry, just hand rinse it under running water. This is to prevent bad odor caused by staying wet and damp for a long time. After rinsing it, just lay it flat or hang it to dry. This saves you both socks and laundry.

Answer (score 1):

Bodyheat is how we dry socks while camping. Putting socks under our shirts or somewhere else warm for 45 minutes to 1.5 hrs usually does the trick

Comment: I red that on the outdoors site and think that's silly. In a camping environment you should have brought a change of dry socks in the first place.

Comment: We bring more than one pair of socks, silly goose. But you never know when you'll need a dry pair.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your socks and feet in plastic wrap.  This would keep your socks and feet dry when stepping into puddles.

Answer (score 0):

Well I hesitate to state the obvious, but if the weather's wet, would it not be possible to wear waterproof boots or shoes? Otherwise, unless you've a warm radiator to lay them on, get a towel, lay the socks on it, roll the towel up and sit on it on a hard surface to squeeze out the worst of the water, and hang the socks up to dry somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have got 2 solutions for it.

1. When you come home for changing your socks, you can hang your wet socks before a [hearth](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hearth+means&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO4OWYu-fJAhVPBY4KHQpyAWQQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=d9tQrhKfoxCX-M%3A).I hope you have a hearth at your home, for facing cold conditions.Thus, on returning  home the next time, your socks will be ready to take.But take care that, they should not burn out due to overheat and so keep them or hang them before your hearth at a safe but at good distance.
2. You can use an [iron machine](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hearth+means&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO4OWYu-fJAhVPBY4KHQpyAWQQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=iron+machine)for drying your wet socks.Literally,it can make us laugh but you can use it if you lack time.Be careful as not to spoil your own socks.