# Stepped in a puddle before a meeting. How to dry a sock quickly?

Tags: clothing, water

I stepped in deep puddle. Darn potholes. I have a meeting in **10 minutes**. How can I dry my sock quickly? *I have spare shoes.*

I tried the washroom hand dryer, but the air blows sideways so I can't dry inside. Also, wadding tissues in the sock makes my foot not fit. Any hacks?

**Edit:** This best answer [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10331/what-to-do-with-wet-socks) requires body heat and 45 minutes, so it is not applicable.

Comment: Is it to late to answer?

Comment: @goodguy5 If you have an answer, please post it below. And if folks finally come to this site through search, please do not send them elsewhere to find that information.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Fair enough. I'm generally hesitant to post answers I haven't tried that I just found online. Give me a minute to get it up. (that's what she said! HEYOO!) Edit: Someone deleted my post and now I can't make an answer.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Why was my other comment deleted? Now no one can use it. Legitimately confused....

Comment: @goodguy5 Please do not use comments to answer questions. Comments do not have the features needed to vet anything you post, so that is why answers are not allowed in comments. That, plus you answered with a link intended to send users *elsewhere* to find that information. We don't do that either. The folks here will work hard to curate this collection of knowledge, so when someone finally finds this site through search, the last thing we want to do is send them *elsewhere* to find that information. I hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: @RobertCartaino The amount in which I would like to discuss this is not appropriate for the comments section (and the comments-->chat interface is confusing). Long story short, give users the chance to turn a comment-answer into a real answer before deleting it.

Comment: @goodguy5 That simply is not how comments work. There's no mechanism to tell unsuspecting users that the information posted very prominently just below the question may actually be incomplete half-answers not to be trusted... while the stuff posted at the bottom are properly vetted and complete. There is also no mechanism to go back and clean that stuff up later (no wiki features in comments), so when unsuspecting users see an "answer" posted very prominently at the top of the page, they may simply assume the issue has been resolved and wont bother posting a proper answer at all. It happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38537/discussion-between-goodguy5-and-robert-cartaino).

Comment: @Steven That answer requires 45 minutes plus. I only had 10 minutes and in an office setting..

Comment: @JustDoIt both questions are about drying socks after getting them wet. While we should not close questions simply because they can have overlap in answers, that does not mean that we shouldn't close questions that have an overlap in answers. We have to examine the questions to see if they are dups, and as both ask about drying socks after getting them wet, they are dups. Just because the other answers in the other question take too long to work for you, doesn't mean you should ask a the same question again. You should leave a comment or bounty on the other question to attract other answers.

Comment: So basically you changed your mind, considering now you're against leaving open this question @Dragonrage

Comment: @JustDoIt can you explain how the two questions are different?

Comment: Situation, this a more specific situation whereas the other one is a general case of wet socks @Dragonrage

Comment: Also the nature of this question makes the answers from the other question inapplicable @Dragonrage

Comment: @JustDoIt this is getting too long for comments, if you wish to continue this, make a meta post.

Comment: I'll just go with the flow, but the irony of the situation is quite funny @Dragonrage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38698/discussion-between-dragonrage-and-just-do-it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up **microwaving** the sock in the office break room because I only had a few minutes before a meeting to get it dry. Here's what worked:

1. Take off the *cotton* sock and ring it out well.
2. Put the sock in the shape of a ring on a microwavable plate for max surface area.
3. Put paper towels over it and under it like a sandwich.
4. Microwave on high (900W) for about 1 minute.
5. Flip the paper-towel-sock sandwich over and replace the wet paper towels (now the top ones) with fresh paper towels, and let the steam out of the microwave. The sock will be hot(!) but it cools in about 10 seconds.
6. Repeat step #5 4 or 5 times until the sock is dry or just lightly damp.

It was a cotton sock (not synthetic) so I think it shrunk a little, but it cooled quickly and I could wear it. Again, with only a few minutes to get the sock dry before a meeting, this worked well in a pinch.

Comment: Now my ramen noodles smell like sweaty microwaved socks :P

Answer (score 0):

Rice is a great way to quickly absorb moisture. Just drop the sock in a containerwith rice and leave it for a while. To help it dry even faster, wring out all of the residual water inside the sock first.

Comment: Would that leave little grains of wet rice in the sock? How long would that take to clean out thoroughly you figure?

Comment: changed it because that was an accident.

Comment: due to the nature and specifics of the question I doubt this is and advisable course of action